# AtributeError при преобразовании звука в текст

Tags: python-3.x, распознавание-речи

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' при преобразовании звука в текст. Помогите, кто сталкивался? Использую библиотеку speech_recognizer.
Пример кода:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
    print("Say something...")
    audio = r.listen(source)

query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU", show_all=True)
print("You said: " + query.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь

```
query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU", show_all=True)
```

Вы указали

show_all=True

И скорее всего метод возвращает список отсюда и ошибка

```
from speech_recognition import Microphone, Recognizer, UnknownValueError, 
RequestError


class SpeechRecognitionExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.microphone = Microphone()
        self.recognizer = Recognizer()
    def run(self):
        print("Минутку тишины, пожалуйста...")
        with self.microphone as microphone:
            self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(microphone)
        while True:
            print("Говорите!")
            try:
                with self.microphone as microphone:
                    audio = self.recognizer.listen(microphone)
                    print("Распознавание...")
                text_value = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru_RU")
                print("Вы сказали: " + text_value.lower())
            except UnknownValueError as error:
                print("UnknownValueError")
            except RequestError as error:
                print("RequestError")

def main():
    application = SpeechRecognitionExample()
    application.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог отметьте его как решение